# Workaround to get data for processing purposes without data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, data-modeling, data-warehouse

In my organization we do not have data warehouse or any kind of intermediate data storage used for data processing.

I need to extract data on daily basis for the last 5 years. 
So to achieve that I run complex stored procedures that inserting the result into Tables, then I write query to join that data and getting the final output.
Then I truncate those tables and starting the process again.

Below is graphical representation of the process:

[image]

The amount of data is growing. To run those stored procedures requires more and more resources.

What would be my best solution to this problem?
I have SSIS tool available.

Comment: The process you have described is an informal data warehouse.  You've copied the data that you need for reporting to a separate logical location.

Comment: Yes. But my organization dont have a data warehouse. So what workaround would be the best?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just extracting data on a daily basis, then fetch daily only the deltas and add those to Table 1, Table 2, Table 3 etc.  No reason to continue loading data daily that has not changed.